# Is there a way to get the subversion history for a list of files?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I'm using intellij and am able to view the svn history for individual files by right clicking on them, which gives me info on when the file was last modified and by whom. Is there a way that I can find this for a list of files, without manually doing it for each and every file? Is there a script I need to write or a method where I can input the file names the svn history will be outputted?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please read `svn help log`, pay attention on second form of log **and** on 4-th sample:

```
svn log ^/trunk@50 foo.c bar.c
```

(with explanation) near bottom of help-text. You have only to define base-PATH for the set of files and build (space-separated) file-list with relative paths for all files

Answer (score 0):

If the files share a parent directory, you can simply `Show History` on that directory instead.  This will show you all changes made to all files in that directory.